# 3d Game Engine for Android which does not require android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, game-engine, google-tv

I am looking for a decent 3d game engine (preferably with physics support) to run on x86 based android machines (GoogleTV etc.). This means that the engine should NOT be dependent on the Android NDK as it is not currently supported on the Google TV.

I've already checked Unity3d, ShiVa3D and libgdx which all run on native code (utilize the Android NDK). So I'm looking for similar engines which could make apps supporting Google TV etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try Gamine http://sourceforge.net/projects/gamine/

Comment: Thanks. Looking into it. It seems to have a low following though.